# Checking the type inside a match statement

Tags: ballerina

I have a requirement to check the type of a variable inside match statement, What is the best method to do this without using if clauses. A sample code would look like following(the sample code is not working).

```
match (typeof val) {
        "time:Date" => {
            return "Date";
        }
        "time:Utc" => {
            return "Time:Utc";
        }
        "time:DateTime" => {
            return "DateTime";
        }
        _ => {
            return "Invalid";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a match guard to check for the type similar to an is check in an if-else statement.

```
function fn(any val) returns string {
    match val {
        var x if x is time:Date => {
            return "Date";
        }
        // ... 
        _ => {
            return "Invalid";
        }
    }
}
```

The `match` statement does a value match. If your requirement is to purely test for type rather than value, using an if-else statement with `is` checks may be the better approach.

```
function fn(any val) returns string {
    if val is time:Date {
        return "Date";
    }

    if val is time:Utc {
        return "Time:Utc";
    }

    // ... 

    return "Invalid";
}
```